# TypeError: operator() missing 1 required positional argument: 'user'

Tags: python, oop, compiler-errors, typeerror

**Python code to generate two random variables that can add up and give an answer**

```
print("What is You Favorite Maths Operation \nAddition(a) \nSubstraction(s) \nMultiplication(M) \nDivision(d)")

#user input operator from the table given
class cooperators:
    def choose(self):
        return input("Choose One Of Them To Solve Some Interesting Problem:")

    def operator(self,user):

        #if you chose a then addition
        if user =='a':
            return True

        #if you chose s then Substraction
        elif user =='s':
            return True

        #if you chose m then multiplication
        elif user =='m':
            return True

        #if you chose d then division
        elif user =='d':
            return False
    def play(self,users):
        randomNumber = random.randint(1, 10)
        if users =='a':
            print(f"Addition: {randomNumber} \n {randomNumber}")
            print("Your answer: ")
            print(f"Correct answer is: {randomNumber}+{randomNumber}")  

t= caloperators()
t.choose()
t.operator()
t.play()
print(t.choose)
print(t.operator)
print(t.play)
```

I am not able to get an answer but getting errors and also if someone can complete the code it will really help to end this project and complete it.

Comment: Hello, may I ask what modules you are using?

Comment: @AgentBiscutt, I am using **import random**

Answer (score 3):

```
t.operator()
```

You're not passing any arguments into this. hence the error.

You can do:

```
a = t.choose()
t.operator(a)
```

since choose() is returning the input.
You're then passing that input into a variable called a, which is then passed into operator(user).
in this case a == user.

You will then have the problem of not passing any arguments into play(users)

which you then can pass a into that too:

```
t.play(a)
```